# Problemas con summernote

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

soy nuevo en la programación y necesito ayuda
quiero que cuando seleccione uno de los nombre lo coloque en la posición en la que se encuentra el cursor

```
<select>selecionar dato</select>
<option value="Emmanuel">Emmanuel</option>
<option value="Cristina">Cristina</option>
<option value="Alicia">Alicia</option>
<option value="Esjani">Esjani</option>

<textarea>
    mucho gusto mi nombre es: (aquí puede estar el cursor) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.(aquí puede estar el cursor) Dolore ipsa molestiae nemo tempore nesciunt, quos obcaecati repellendus sequi dolores exercitationem quisquam voluptatibus porro tempora quis aperiam nobis eum dignissimos,(aquí puede estar el cursor)
</textarea>
```

Comment: aqui se ocupa JS, nos muestras lo que has intentado

Comment: no tengo nada de Js, porque no se como realizarlo

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer es antes que nada capturar la posición del cursor antes de perder el foco en tu input y almacenarlo en un hidden por ejemplo. Luego al seleccionar una opción en tu select, debemos tomar el texto que contiene e insertar dicho valor en la posición previamente guardada. Finalmente le regresamos el foco para poder continuar escribiendo sin tener que recurrir al uso del ratón. Saludos!

**Ejemplo:**

```js
function insertValue(value){
let pos = document.getElementById("ultimaPosicion").value;
 
var textoActual = document.getElementById("input").value;
var textoInsertar = value;
var position = pos;

var output = [textoActual.slice(0, position), textoInsertar, textoActual.slice(position)].join('');

document.getElementById("input").value = output;
document.getElementById("input").focus();
}
function savePos(pos){
document.getElementById("ultimaPosicion").value = pos;
}
```

```css
textarea{width:100%}
```

```html
<select onChange="insertValue(this.value)">
<option>selecionar dato...</option>
<option value="Emmanuel">Emmanuel</option>
<option value="Cristina">Cristina</option>
<option value="Alicia">Alicia</option>
<option value="Esjani">Esjani</option>
</select>

<textarea id="input" onblur="savePos(this.selectionEnd)"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" id="ultimaPosicion" value="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

yo utilizaría un `addEventListener` que dispare una función cuando se seleccione un `option` nuevo

Agrega un nuevo `option` con el texto 'Selecciona uno', así la primera vez tu `textArea` aparecerá vacío

En tu `js` crea la función `nuevoTexto` con una variable donde incluyas todo el texto del textArea y lo concatenas con `option.value`, éste contendrá el value del option cada que selecciones uno nuevo. Al final haces un return del `textArea.textContent con el nuevo texto. El css solo es para hacer el textArea mas grande ;)

Saludos

```js
var textArea = document.querySelector('textArea'); 
var option  = document.querySelector('select');

function nuevoTexto () {
  var newTextContent = 'mucho gusto mi nombre es: ' + option.value + ' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. ' + option.value + ' Dolore ipsa molestiae nemo tempore nesciunt, quos obcaecati repellendus sequi dolores exercitationem quisquam voluptatibus porro tempora quis aperiam nobis eum dignissimos, ' + option.value;
  return textArea.textContent = newTextContent;
}

option.addEventListener('change', nuevoTexto, false)
```

```css
textArea{
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<br>
<select>
    <option value="null">Selecciona uno</option>
    <option value="Emmanuel">Emmanuel</option>
    <option value="Cristina">Cristina</option>
    <option value="Alicia">Alicia</option>
    <option value="Esjani">Esjani</option>
</select>
<br>
<textarea>
</textarea>
```